# Custom JS affects table formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote a JS function to style the column `bar_link` from a long link to the short version in the image.

[image] 
The problem is that the column name for the third column disappeared. Also, the styling only applies if I go to another page and then back again.

Desired result:

[image]

What might be the reason(s) for this behavior?

As reuested, I attach here the custom JS I added to this page:

```
return function () {

var f = function () { };

f.version = "1";

f.afterDraw = function () {

    function d() {
        var txt = document.querySelector('[id^=data-table] > tbody').getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
            txt[i].textContent = txt[i].textContent.toString().slice(-4);
        }
    }
    d()
    var change_page = document.querySelector("[id^=data-table]");
    change_page.addEventListener("click", d);

    var filter = document.querySelector('[id^=data-table] > div > div > div > div.dataTables_scrollHead > div > table > thead > tr');
    filter.addEventListener('click', d);

    var close = document.querySelector('body > div.super-modal.edit-mode.in-dashboard.ui-droppable > div.modal-button-bar > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a');
    filter.addEventListener('click', d);
};
return f;
}();
```

Comment: Kinda hard to say i think without seeing any kind of code

Comment: I will add it asap

Comment: "go to another page and then go back" - sounds like a caching issue.

Comment: Code added, sorry I did not provide it before.